# Formatting numbers with commas PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

How do i correctly format numbers with commas. Example

I wand 10000 to be 10,000 I know i can do it using below code

```
number_format(10000)
```

Issue is that if is a number with decimals it tends to remove the decimal.

Ex: 10000.50 it will display the number as 10,001

How can i get around this and correctly display numbers with and without decimals.

Comment: NumberFormatter : http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a clear doc for this function:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 3):

The right way to format numbers using php is to use the in-built function `number_format`

`string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )`
There are four parameters you can pass to the function:

1. $number: which is the number you want to format.
2. $decimals: It is the number of decimal places that you want to format upto.
3. $dec_point: It is the character you want to use (if needed) instead of the usual `"."` used to represent the decimal point.
4. $thousands_sep : This is the character you want to use to seperate the thousands places with e.g. ",".

**Documentation** for the function can be found [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

So, In your question, you will replace `number_format(10000)` with `number_format(10000,2)`

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this 
number_format(10000.50);
output will come this format 10,001

Answer (score 0):

number_format(10000,3); number_format(10000,2);